# regarding elastic search nested filter

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have the below mapping,

```
{
  "wms": {
    "mappings": {
      "item": {
        "properties": {
          "barcode": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "comments": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "sku": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "brandName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "code": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and below data.

```
{
  "_index": "wms",
  "_type": "item",
  "_id": "100006868381",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "id": 100006868381,
    "createdBy": null,
    "createdOn": null,
    "lastModifiedOn": null,
    "barcode": "100006868381",
    "sku": {
      "id": 396829,
      "createdBy": null,
      "createdOn": null,
      "lastModifiedOn": null,
      "name": null,
      "code": "KIRAHDBG00598",
      "lastUser": null,
      "adminDisabled": null,
      "description": null,
      "vendorArticleNo": null,
      "vendorArticleName": null,
      "size": null,
      "brandId": null,
      "brandName": "KIARA",
      "brandCode": null,
      "articleTypeId": null,
      "articleTypeName": null,
      "articleTypeCode": null,
      "remarks": null,
      "jitSourced": null,
      "gtin": null,
      "enabled": null,
      "version": null
    },
    "quality": null,
    "itemStatus": null,
    "warehouseId": null,
    "enabled": null,
    "poId": null,
    "poBarcode": null,
    "comments": "Created for PO: RNSI233380213-00Thu Aug 21 10:40:36 IST 2014",
    "orderId": null,
    "bin": null,
    "lotId": null,
    "lotBarcode": null,
    "poSkuId": null,
    "grnSkuId": null,
    "grnBarcode": null,
    "inwardedOn": null,
    "rejectReason": null,
    "rejectReasonDescription": null,
    "cartonBarcode": null
  }
}
```

I am using spring-elasticsearch data but without repositories. I mean using the template itself.
when I do a search on barcode, it works fine. and all seems okay when I run a nested query on `sku.id`

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "sku.id": "396829"
            }
          },
          "path": "sku"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but things are not working when I search on `sku.code`

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "sku.code": "KIRAHDBG00598"
            }
          },
          "path": "sku"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using below code for search.

```
filterBuilder = FilterBuilders.termFilter(name, value);
if (name.contains(".")) {
    String firstPart = name.split("\\.")[0];
    return FilterBuilders.nestedFilter(firstPart, filterBuilder);
}
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 20);
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), filterBuilder))
        .withPageable(pageable)
        .build();
Page<E> sampleEntities = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery, this.entryClass);
```

can you tell what I am missing?

Comment: Please, fix the title of your question. It should actually be the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your field **"sku.code"** is **analyzed**.
The **term filter** expects **not analyzed** fields.
That is the reason why it doesn't work.

For your long field, that was no problem, because numeric fields don't suffer of this problem.

I suggest you to use a **match query** (there is no problem in putting a match query inside of a filter), that works with **analyzed** fields.

So, this should work for you.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "filter": {
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "code": "KIRAHDBG00598"
              }
            }
          },
          "path": "sku"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you are not familiar with **analyzed** and **not analyzed** fields, I suggest you testing small examples with **match** and **term** queries.

Comment: i realised i had to use not_analyzed, but i am kind of struggling to get the exact query using spring-data-elasticsearch. i mean when i use curl i get response for this query. any pointers on how to get this right.

`{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "sku.code": "KIRAHDBG00598"
            }
          },
          "path": "sku"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Then, you have to change your index.
You mapping has the field "sku.code" as analyzed (this is the default). You have to set it as not analyzed.

Comment: Example for your type "item":
{
  "item" : {
        "properties" : {
   "sku" : {
    "type" : "nested" ,
    "properties" : {
     "brandName" : { "type" : "integer" },
     "code"  : { "type" : "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
     "id"  : { "type" : "long" }
    }
   },
   "code" :  { "type" : "integer" }
        }
    }
}